# What does clipping at Canon or FinePix ISO image mean?

Tags: image, matlab, noise

I'm trying to review about the camera noise.
Also I have reference as following  http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/

But I want to know what does clipping mean at the following code.

:code

```
%% ====================================================================================================================================
            %% LOAD BITMAP/RAW IMAGE    %  raw-data images which are loaded below can be downloaded from http://www.cs.tut.fi/~foi/sensornoise.html
            %% ====================================================================================================================================
            if 1 %% load "noise-free" image and add noise   (OTHERWISE LOAD RAW DATA, SEE BELOW)
                add_noise=1;                % add noise to image
                a=0.1^2;   b=0.04^2;        % noise parameters a,b
                %    a=0.1^2;   b=0.02^2;       % noise parameters a,b
                %    a=0.0^2;   b=0.2^2;        % noise parameters a,b
                %    a=(1/30);  b=0.1^2;        % noise parameters a,b

                clipping_below=1;   %  on/off   [keep off for pure-poissonian (no gaussian terms) noise, since there are no negative errors]
                clipping_above=1;   %  on/off
                prior_density=1;                 %  type of prior density to use for ML    (0)
                %                                %    1: zero_one uniform prior density [0,1];


                %     y=im2double(imread('image_man1024.tiff'));
                %     y=im2double(imread('image_testpat1024.tiff'));
                y=im2double(imread('y_piecewise.tif'));
                %     y=im2double(imread('y_piecewise_fibo.tif'));

            else %%  RAW  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                add_noise=0;  %% DO NOT ADD NOISE TO RAW-DATA (IT HAS ENOUGH NOISE ALREADY! :) )
                clipping_below=1;  %%%% on off   %% RAW-DATA IS ASSUMED TO BE CLIPPED FROM ABOVE AND BELOW
                clipping_above=1;  %%%% on off
                prior_density=0;                 %  type of prior density to use for ML    (0)
                %                                %    0: zero_infty uniform prior density (R+);  (default, use this for raw-data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clipping in general is what happens when a value exceeds some threshold and is forced to that threshold. Also known as saturation (when it's accidental), clamping (when deliberate) and others.

It's common in digital systems, including digital photography, where you use a binary value with a specified number of bits to represent some data. That binary value then has upper and lower limits implied by the number of bits and the way they are used to encode values.

In this context it looks like the code is generating noise to add to an image. The expression that generates the noise is not quoted but the comments suggest a Poisson distribution, which is a mathematical function which could produce outputs exceeding the dynamic range of the image. The two flags `clipping_below` and `clipping_above` are control flags which allow the user to specify whether those values should be clipped, i.e. constrained to the upper and lower limits of the datatype.

Comment: Thanks Sir, and my apologies. I have mistake wrong another question. But I have just role-backed.

Comment: I think some kind of commercial camera have those kind of number of clipping up or down..but  I'm not sure. so I want to know more.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the site anyway : )

Comment: All cameras will perform this clipping under certain circumstances, it's a necessary condition of the way they represent physical data (i.e. the amount of light hitting a pixel of the sensor) using binary numbers. A jpg will have 16 bits available and a RAW file 24, and that many bits can only be used to represent a finite number of values. Any value outside that range is clipped. As a photographer you (or your camera) would alter the exposure settings in order to fit the incoming data into the dynamic range without clipping, but if you can't do that it has to clip.